# How can I implement and register iapplication interface in e4 rcp?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

Is there a way to create and implement the iapplication interface in Eclipse rcp? Or is there a way to alter the workspace lock error message thrown by e4application class in e4 rcp?

Comment: Please note: it's "there", not "der".

Comment: That will not happen from next time. Typed it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Implement IApplication interface (or extend E4Application class). Assuming that you named your class "ExtendedE4Application", add the following lines to your plugin.xml

```
   <extension
         id="ExtendedE4Application"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application
            cardinality="singleton-global"
            thread="main"
            visible="true">
         <run
               class="your.package.ExtendedE4Application">
         </run>
      </application>
   </extension>
```